# Matplotlib error Line2d object s not iterable error in tkinter callback nothing shows up

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, scipy

The code is shown below. I am attempting to animate using vectors calculated earlier a figure window is opened so i know it gets this far and the vectors are being calclated correctly. But matplotlib oututs nothing but the figure window I have no idea why. Please help.

```
#finally animateing
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim = (-1000,1000) ,ylim = (-1000,1000))#limits were arbitrary
#line = ax.plot([],[])
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)

# initialization function: plot the background of each frame
def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
    return line,


def animate(i):
 x = time_vec[i]
 y = complex_vec[i]
 #y1 = real_vec[i] 
 #y2 = modulus_vec[i]
 line.set_data(x,y)
 #line.set_data(x,y1)
 #line.set_data(x,y2) 
 return line,

animation_object = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func= init, frames = num_files,interval = 30, blit = True)

#turnn this line on to save as mp4
#anim.save("give it a name.mp4", fps = 30, extra-args = ['vcodec', 'libx264'])
plt.show()
```

**THE FULL ERROR MESSAGE IS SHOWN BELOW**

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "the_animation.py", line 71, in <module>
    plt.show()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 145,     in show
    _show(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backend_bases.py",     line 117, in __call__
    self.mainloop()
  File     "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line     69, in mainloop
    Tk.mainloop()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 366, in mainloop
    _default_root.tk.mainloop(n)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1484, in __call__
    def __call__(self, *args):
```

**MINIMAL EXAMPLE**

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
complex_vec = np.arange(5,6,.001)
real_vec = np.arange(7,8,.001)
time_vec = np.arange(0,1,.001)
num_files = np.size(time_vec)
#creating the modulus vector
modulus_vec = np.zeros(np.shape(complex_vec))
for k in range (0,complex_vec.size):
    a = complex_vec[k]
    b = real_vec[k]
    calc_modulus = np.sqrt(a**2 + b**2)
    modulus_vec[k] = calc_modulus
#finally animateing
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim = (-1000,1000) ,ylim = (-1000,1000))#limits were     arbitrary
#line = ax.plot([],[])
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)

# initialization function: plot the background of each frame
def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
    return line,


def animate(i):
    x = time_vec[i]
    y = complex_vec[i]
    y1 = real_vec[i] 
    y2 = modulus_vec[i]
    line.set_data(x,y)
    line.set_data(x,y1)
    line.set_data(x,y2) 
    return line,

animation_object = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func= init, frames = num_files,interval = 30, blit = True)

#turnn this line on to save as mp4
#anim.save("give it a name.mp4", fps = 30, extra-args = ['vcodec',     'libx264'])
plt.show()
```

Comment: what line are you receiving the error your title reads on?

Comment: thats the even weirder part i will post the erroro message in just a moment

Comment: @Ioma you sure that's the full error? Because your error output has no error

Comment: you are right i suppossed that because nothing was showing up i would get an error but this just pops up so i assumed it was an error but I guess not however I am realy confused now because even after running for 2 hrs it still does not show anything just the figure window no axes nothing

Comment: @Ioma do you have some sort of minimal example you can post or link to this file if it's a single script? it's difficult to debug with no solid error output or access to the file

Comment: I can make a minimal example

Comment: minimal example posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is in your `animate` function, you're using `set_data` multiple times which does not do what you think it does. You're using it like an *append*, when it's a *set*. The arguments should be two arrays, containing the respective x and y values for that line. This will animate your minimal example:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

complex_vec = np.arange(5,6,.001)
real_vec = np.arange(7,8,.001)
time_vec = np.arange(0,1,.001)
num_files = np.size(time_vec)

#creating the modulus vector
modulus_vec = np.zeros(np.shape(complex_vec))
for k in range (0,complex_vec.size):
    a = complex_vec[k]
    b = real_vec[k]
    calc_modulus = np.sqrt(a**2 + b**2)
    modulus_vec[k] = calc_modulus

#finally animateing
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim = (-1,1) ,ylim = (-1,15))#limits were     arbitrary
#line = ax.plot([],[])
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)

# initialization function: plot the background of each frame
def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
    return line,

def animate(i):
    x = time_vec[i]
    y = complex_vec[i]
    y1 = real_vec[i] 
    y2 = modulus_vec[i]
    # notice we are only calling set_data once, and bundling the y values into an array
    line.set_data(x,np.array([y, y1, y2]))
    return line,

animation_object = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, 
                                           animate, 
                                           init_func= init, 
                                           frames = num_files,
                                           interval = 30, 
                                           blit = True)

#turnn this line on to save as mp4
#anim.save("give it a name.mp4", fps = 30, extra-args = ['vcodec',     'libx264'])
plt.show()
```

Your previous attempt was setting the **x** and **y** values, then overwriting the previous with a new **x** and **y**, then doing that once again.